# UnCheck ALL checkbox not working while using cascading multi select dropdown in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, reportingservices-2005

I am using SQL server 2008 R2.
I have two multiselect dropdown in my report. Second dropdown values populate based on 1st dropdown selected value.

**Expectation**

Select ALL checkbox in 1st dropdown, second dropdown values are loaded.Then I deselect ALL checkbok in 1st dropdown, 1st dropdown checked values are unchecked and second dropdown is disabled.

**Output**

When I deselect All checkbox in 1st dropdown,the 1st dropdown checkbox are didn't deselect and 2nd dropdown showed previous selected value.

You have any ideas, please Let me know

Comment: Have you set both avail;able and default parameters based on your first parameter?

Comment: @AlanSchofield Yes I set it.

Comment: I think that once a value has been selected, you cannot then select nothing. Whether this is a bug or by design I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you select 1 or more values in the 1st dropdown then the value of 2nd dropdown should refresh automatically (ordering of your parameters is important).

Whereas if you **UNCHECK ALL** the value in the 1st dropdown then the 2nd dropdown will not refresh to **DEFAULT** value which is by the design of the SSRS. Here is the link from microsoft community.

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/268032/default-does-not-get-refreshed-for-cascading-parameters